# In Java about Synchronization and monitor in Thread

Tags: java, synchronization

I read that a thread that owns a monitor can reenter the same monitor if it need to do so, how that can be achieved. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [This](http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/java/threads/reentrant.html) example may help shed some light for you.

Comment: Sample code, please... And more importantly, what do you want to achieve?

Comment: This is nothing that can be "achieved", it is part of how concurrency synchronization works in the Java language.

Comment: All i want to know is that in what situation a thread will reenter in a monitor that it owns, what will be a real world scenario.

Comment: Although i find Jeffery link useful but in what applications this kind of situation may occur. Any real world example will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function takes ownership of a monitor:

```
function_a() {
    synchronized(monitor) {
        function_b();
    }
}
```

Now let's say `function_b` looks like this:

```
function_b() {
    synchronized(monitor) {
        do_something();
    }
}
```

In `function_b`, our thread "reenters" the monitor by declaring a second synchronization on it.  Since the thread already owns the monitor, the thread can continue into the second synchronized block.

Comment: Thanks Warren Dew...I am looking forward for a real world scenario